# Force to download a module on a remote site

Tags: drush, composer

How can I force to download a Drupal 8 module on a remote Drupal 7 site?

I tried the following commands, but they let me choose Drupal 7 versions.

- `drush @remote.dev dl --default-major=8 composer`

  > There are no stable releases for project composer.
  > Choose one of the available releases for composer:
  > [0]  :  Cancel
  > [1]  :  7.x-1.x-dev  -  2013-Sep-30  -  Development, Recommended
- `drush @remote.dev dl composer-8`

  > There are no stable releases for project composer.
  > Choose one of the available releases for composer:
  > [0]  :  Cancel
  > [1]  :  7.x-1.x-dev  -  2013-Sep-30  -  Development, Recommended

How does Drush detect the version of the remote site?
Maybe I can edit that and restore it after the download, or I can override some Drush parameters to forcefully show all releases.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest --default-major. Since that does not seem to work, I can only recommend to download the module outside of a Drupal site and then move it into place.

`drush dl composer-7 --destination=/tmp && drush rsync @self:/tmp/composer @remote-dev:sites/all/modules`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
drush @remote.dev exec drush @none dl composer --default-major=8
```

which will execute `drush` (either `exec` or `ssh`) on remote using `@none` environment, which will force Drush to not try to recognise the major version of Drupal which you're running in the current folder. Without using `@none`, this is [expected behavior](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1735#issuecomment-152911445).